# how to make twitter like follow button using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

### Client side code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(" a .follow").click(function() {

    var thiss = $(this);
    var state = thiss.attr("data-state");
    var id = thiss.attr("id");
    var follow = thiss.attr("data-follow");
    alert(value + id + flag);
    $.post("<?php echo base_url()?>profile/insert_follow", {
      state: state,
      id: id,
      follow: follow
    }, function(data) {

      if (thiss.hasClass("follow")) {

        var abc = "<a class="btn btn-info btn-follow unfollow" data-state="2" data-follow="<? php echo $artist_info - > id ?>" data-id="<? php echo $this->session->userdata('username') ?>">Following</a>";
        thiss.append(abc);

      }
      elseif(thiss.hasClass("unfollow")) {

        var abc1 = "<a class="btn btn-info btn-follow follow" data-state="2" data-follow=" <? php echo $artist_info->id ?> " data-id=" <? php echo $this->session->userdata('username') ?> ">Follow</a>";
        thiss.append(abc1);
      }
      $('.followers').children('span').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

### Server side code

```
public function insert_follow(){
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $follows = $_POST['follows'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $data1=array(
            'id'=>$id,
            'follows' =>$follows,
            'state' =>$state
                    );

    $query=$this->hbmodel->follow_artist($data1);


}
```

Here I am trying to update the content of the element `.follow` with the given html information in var `abc`. But it's not working. The code also includes the contents for ajax. Maybe the problem might be with 304 status that I get when I load `jquery` and `bootstrap.min.js` file. Here is the function in codeigniter controller. You can use [this link](http://projects.a100websolutions.in/create-button-like-twitter-follow/) for the rough idea of what i am trying to do

Comment: `"it's not working"` doesn't really describe the problem.  *How* is it "not working"?  What *specific* way does it fail?  When you debug this, where/how *exactly* does it fail?

Comment: I see multiple problems in your syntax. `elseif` should be `else if`, `thiss` should be `this`, you should not declare a `variable` named `this`, is it `a.follow` or `a .follow` (huge differences), you should separate your `ajax query` from the rest of your code in another `function`

Comment: Any errors in your console? `var abc = "<a class="btn btn-info btn-follow unfollow"` this seems to me your mixing up the quotes. Try this: `var abc = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-follow unfollow" [...] ';`

Comment: I have change the code on sublime but the browser still shows the error on the line for the same cause. SyntaxError: missing ; before statement why? i have saved the page after editing @empiric

Answer (score 2):

From what i see, when you create you variable `abc` and `abc1` you try to `concat` `string`. Your code should be like this:

```
var abc = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-follow unfollow" data-state="2" data-follow="<? php echo $artist_info->id ?>" data-id="<? php echo $this->session->userdata('username') ?>">Following</a>';
```

instead of:

```
var abc = "<a class="btn btn-info btn-follow unfollow" data-state="2" data-follow="<? php echo $artist_info->id ?>" data-id="<? php echo $this->session->userdata('username') ?>">Following</a>";
```

The subtility is in the single quote at the begining and the end of the element you are trying to add;

Plus you are adding plain text to your DOM. Try this instead:

`thiss.append($(abc));`

of

`thiss.append(abc);`

But this is a wild guess based on the question being unclear.

Comment: I have change the code on sublime but the browser still shows the error on the line for the same cause. SyntaxError: missing ; before statement why? i have saved the page after editing @chax

Comment: Which line? and If you use chrome, there is an option to not keep the cache when in developper's mode (F12). Try that as well.

Comment: Empty string passed to getElementById(). alright this is the error i am getting now everytime i click on the follow link

Comment: Is `data` containing something? add this line `console.log(data)` right before `$('.followers...`

Comment: The console appear when you press F12 in almost all browser under chrome it's F12 -> Console

Comment: hey would you look at the chat